# Fastest way to transfer buffer/texture data from GPU to CPU

Tags: c++, opengl

As the question implies, I'm trying to transfer some buffer data from the gpu to the cpu and I want to do it fast.

**Specifically, I'd like to transfer a 640x480 float buffer in less than 1ms.**

**Question 1**: Is this possible in less than 1ms?

---

Whether it is or not, I'd like to find out what the fastest way is. Everything I've tried up to this point is by using FBOs. Here are the different methods and their respective average time for transfer. All of these are run right after binding to the FBO and rendering on the textures. As I'm no expert, there might be mistakes in my code or I might be doing unnecessary steps so please let me know. The transfers, however, have all been checked to be successful. I transfer everything to cv::Mat objects.

**1)Using glReadPixels -  < 3.1ms**

```
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTexture);
   glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT,mat.data);
```

**2)Using glGetTexImage - <2.9ms**

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,depthTexture);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, mat.data);
```

**3)Using PBO with glGetTexImage - <2.3ms**

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, 0);
mat.data = (uchar*)glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);
```

Before I go on, I understand that I don't use PBOs to their full potential since I immediately call glMapBuffer but there is no other process for the cpu to do at the moment. The texture is drawn the moment I have the necessary data and the texture data is necessary for me to move on. Despite all this, PBOs still seem faster.

Here's something interesting(to me at least). These are measured in debug mode. **In release mode they are all 1ms slower.**

**Question 2:** Why are they slower in release mode? Can I change this?

**Question 3:** Are there any other ways I can try to do the transfer?

**Extra notes on Q3:**

1. I read somewhere that the integrated graphics card can have faster access. Is this a thing? How would I make use of this? Is this connected to GL_INTEL_map_texture?
2. I barely know what CUDA is but it seems there is a way to do the transfer faster using it. Is this true?
3. Will reading the depth buffer instead of a texture be faster?

Comment: You can try to use multiple PBOs (e.g. 2, 3) and switch them every frame. This way on each frame you start transfering in one PBO and instead of waiting for it you immediately start processing the data from other PBO (which was filled on the last frame). On the next frame you switch buffers, start transfering in another PBO and start processing the data you requested on the previous frame. You get a little bit better utilization of GPU (yet you need to benchmark anyway), but in exchange your frames arrive with 1 frame latency (e.g. it's crucial in Augmented Reality)

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov I'm trying to estimate the pose of an object given an image. I could do what you say about the image of the scene but that is not what worries me. For every frame I estimate the pose of the detected object in 7 steps. In each step I render an estimation and grab its depth buffer to generate the next pose estimation. What I'm trying to say is that each texture creation depends on the previous texture data. So , I need the read to be completed before moving on. I hope I made sense.

Comment: "*Is this possible in less than 1ms?*" It depends on your hardware.

Comment: Make sure you measure the right thing. I.e. do something like `glFinish(); start=timestamp(); glReadPixels(); end=timestamp; print(end-start)` in the non-PBO case. I bet you can get less than 2ms for then on reasonable hardware (I get around 0.5 .. 0.6ms for that). The issue is not the transfer speed, but the latency, and that is induced by the rendering work which is queued up at this point. GPUs are simply not made for optimizing latency, but for optimizing throughput. They like big batches of work, and giving them just a bit and immediately reading that back is not the way to go.

Comment: @derhass Wow, this was gold to me. Thanks! It seems all the methods are close to 1ms. I always thought that `glDrawArrays` waits until rendering is complete. I mean, no one mentioned the opposite in the courses I took. I still have a problem of course but it's a different one. So, this extra 1.5ms that I was measuring (essentially glFinish) , is it mostly rendering? I mean, do I have a chance of reducing it by drawing less vertices or not generating color?

Comment: Well, if you can reduce the amount of rendering work, then you can reduce that time a bit. But you still have the overhead of the GPU driver prepraring a new command buffer, sending it to the GPU, and the GPU starting to work on it. If you do the immediate readback, this can't work in an asynchronous manner. THis means the GPU will get a spike of work, but then run out of work and be on idle until the next bit of work is there, It won't be able to ultilize all hw units to a reasonable degree, and due to the long idle times, the driver might even clock it down.

Comment: Your algorithm as you stated it in some earlier comment is simply not friendly to GPU/CPU interoperation.

Comment: @derhass So, I suppose most of that time is taken up by the process you just described. I must be off somewhere because I'm strictly following a paper and that's the way the author implemented their method. I knew they were using glReadPixels and that's what confused me at first since mine was slower. I'll take a look at their rendering process.

Comment: Depending on the data type you request in your `glReadPixels`, OpenGL may convert the values from one data type to another (e.g., 32-bit integer values to [0.0, 1.0] float values), which may take some time (and is generally done on the CPU).  You might try some different data format values (e.g., `GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV` in your retrieval calls and see if you get different speeds, particularly if you're using a 24-bit depth buffer).

Comment: Regarding your main Q3 question: perhaps.  It sounds like your algorithm is synchronous (i.e., you need the depth values before you can continue processing).  However, if that's not the case, you can hide a lot of the readback latency with asynchronous data transfers.

And for your question about integrated graphics (IG), again perhaps.  IG systems use the same memory for the GPU and the CPU (they're often called _unified memory systems_).  As such, in certain instances, mapped buffers may be accessible on the CPU without a data transfer, but may have restrictions on data layout.